# turn.js Swipe and Pinch on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, gestures

I want to use turn.js to create online catalog, dedicated for ipad. I want to keep ability to zoom (i left user-scalable attribute with its default value). Swipe gesture to turn pages would be also useful, like on http://www.turnjs.com/ but when you try to zoom, even on official website, pages will turn after pinch gesture.

I suppose it happens because start of pinch gesture works the same way like swipe - I mean one finger slide. There is condition to turn the page only when touchmove event is made by only one finger (e.originalEvent.touches.length == 1) but I guess before swipe (one finger) becomes pinch (two fingers touches the screen) browser sees first event swipe, next event pinch separately. Same way when somebody take fingers off the screen (it never happens in exactly the same time).

I tried to change e.originalEvent.touches to e.originalEvent.changedTouches to get count of fingers that were used in event, but it also doesn't work like i want it to.

Any simple idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Multitouch gestures can be added by [jGestures](https://jgestures.codeplex.com/).

More information for the usage with turn.js: [GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/85#issuecomment-27269292)